# Next JS - API utility folder structure

Tags: api, next.js

I'm using Next JS and the api routes to create my apis. I have 2 questions if anyone can answer.

1. If I want to use a utility function or global constant variables that I need to include in multiple api files where is the best place to store it in? And to import them using relative paths?
2. Is there an example of a Next JS project that isn't just your basic api routes tutorial to learn from in terms of folder structures?

Answer (score 23):

You can save your util functions on a utils folder on the root of your project folder.

```
|-root
  |-components
    |-Navbar.js
    |-Footer.js
  |-styles
    |-global.css 
    |-navbar.module.css   
    |-footer.module.css        
  |-pages
    |-api
      |-users.js
    |-index.js
  |-utils
    |- dbConnect.js
```

Lets say you want to import dbConnect.js from `pages/api/user.js`

- Relative import:

`import dbConnect from '../../utils/dbConnect';`

- Absolute import:

`import dbConnect from 'src/utils/dbConnect';`

Here is a link to an example project that may help you: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose

If you are interested in using Absolute Imports you can check this documentation link:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases

Comment: How can I make sure that the utils for the API are not bundled into the client?

Comment: To answer myself: anything that is not imported from the client code (and only imported in the API code) should not be bundled into the client by default.

Comment: @Risadinha thank you for the follow up, this was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Risadinha Your comment helped me - having a utils/helpers.js and an utils/api_helpers.js to avoid client and api imports from the same file solved my issue